In beamer, can I have a caption only in article mode, but some of its content in all modes?
I have a beamer frame that I process in both regular beamer and article mode. I would like to have some text appear in all modes, but in article mode that text should appear within a \caption command.
Here is a MWE (Comment out Line 1 and uncomment Line 2 to get the article mode):
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    Lorem ipsum
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.618\textwidth]{example-image}
        \mode<article>{\caption{foo bar}}
        \mode<presentation>{bar}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

This does exactly what I want: in article mode there is a caption foo bar, and in presentation mode only bar with no caption. But in my real case, bar is a longer bit of text and I'd rather not repeat it.
This is what I'm going for, but obviously it won't work because of the imbalanced braces.
\mode<article>{\caption{foo
    bar
\mode<article>{}}

I thought maybe the “second flavor” of \mode could be used, but I haven't gotten it to work. Something like this?
\begin{frame}
    Lorem ipsum
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.618\textwidth]{example-image}
        \mode<article>
            \caption{ foo
        
            \mode<all>{bar}

        }
        \mode
        <all>
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}


You can save the long text in a macro, and then reuse it twice, one time in a caption, another time in an ordinary paragraph.

You could use a caption in both cases, but remove the Figure: part in beamer. This way it will look like normal text:
\documentclass{beamer}
%\documentclass{article}\usepackage{beamerarticle}\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Lorem ipsum
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.618\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
        \setbeamertemplate{caption}{\insertcaption\par}
        \caption{\only<article>{foo} bar}
    \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}


I thought about this, and it's pretty close. I think it's also necessary to set the lengths \abovecaptionskip and \belowscaptionskip to zero.

@MatthewLeingang You can of course change them if you would like.

I should say, it's not necessary, but for purposes of vertical centering I'd rather not add this extra space.
